# Proof of the convergence of a function at a point

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

Here's the problem:

Let $I$ be an open interval and let $x \in I$.  Prove that if $f:I \setminus \{x\} \to \mathbb{R}$ does not converge to $L$ at $x$, then there are an $\epsilon > 0$ and a sequence $\{z_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ so that $\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n = x$, $z_n \in I \setminus \{x\}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and:

$$|f(z_n)-L| \geq \epsilon$$

for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

---

Proof Attempt:

Suppose that $f$ does not converge to $L$ at $x$. Then, there exists a sequence $\{z_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $z_n \in I \setminus \{x\}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n = x$ but:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f(z_n) \neq L$$

That means that:

$$\exists \epsilon > 0: \forall N \in \mathbb{N}: \exists n \geq N: |f(z_n)-L| \geq \epsilon$$

The goal is to construct a subsequence of $\{z_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with the desired property. Define the following set:

$$A = \{n \in \mathbb{N}: |f(z_n)-L| \geq \epsilon \}$$

Since $A$ is non-empty, it has a minimum element $min(A)$. Define $z_{n_1} := z_{min(A)}$. Once $z_{n_k}$ is obtained, consider the following set:

$$A' = \{n \in \mathbb{N}: (|f(z_n)-L| \geq \epsilon) \land (n > n_k) \}$$

This set is non-empty so it has a minimal element $min(A')$. Then, we defined $z_{n_{k+1}} := z_{min(A')}$. This defines a subsequence of $\{z_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ that converges to $x$ and also has the desired property. This proves the result.

Does the argument above work? If it doesn't, why? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works I think, except for one little mistake.
$\exists \epsilon > 0: \forall N \in \mathbb{N}: \exists n \in \mathbb{N}: |f(z_n)-L| \geq \epsilon$

I think you mean $\exists n\in \mathbb N:n\geq N\vee |f(z_n)-L|\geq \epsilon$

Comment: Hey, the definition of convergence of a sequence as presented was:

$$\forall \epsilon > 0: \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \forall n \geq N: |a_n-L| < \epsilon$$

So, I'm just flipping the quantifiers. I know that in some texts, they do put the "$\forall n \geq N: |a_n-L| < \epsilon$" portion as an implication.

Comment: Both are right but... where is $n\geq N$ in your formula?

Comment: Oh right crap, I just realized that I made an idiotic typo. I'm so stupid

Comment: Why would we need the axiom of choice, though? I've defined the sequence inductively, with each step being justified completely? Where would we need the axiom of choice in this?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I mean, do you know how to prove "there exists a sequence {zn}∞n=1 such that zn∈I∖{x} for all n∈N and limn→∞zn=x but: limn→∞f(zn)≠L"

Comment: Well, given that that is the definition of the limit of a function in my book, it's just the negated statement of the definition. 

However, I assume that you're asking how this would be done if we started with the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the limit of a function. So, we can show that the sequential definition is equivalent to the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition. 

So, suppose that:

$$\exists \epsilon > 0: \forall \delta > 0: 0 < |z-x| < \delta \land |f(z)-L| \geq \epsilon$$

Comment: @AbhijeetVats The fact is they are not equivalent without axiom of choice.

Comment: continued...... So, use that to recursively construct a sequence that converges to $x$ by letting $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$. That sequence will always converge to $x$ but $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(z_n) \neq L$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113234/discussion-between-abhijeet-vats-and-sui).